# How to enumerate elements in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

I have 1484 numerical values in my vector I want to calculate how many of each do I have.Numbers are from 1 to 8.
I have tried like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
vector<int> res;
int sum1,sum2,sum3,sum4,sum5,sum6,sum7,sum8;

std::ifstream inputFile1("/home/milenko/cl.dat");

if (inputFile1) {        
    int value;
    while ( inputFile1 >> value ) {
        res.push_back(value);
    }
}

switch (res) {
case 1:
sum1=sum1+1
  break;
case 2:
sum2=sum2+1
  break;
case 3:
sum3=sum3+1
  break;
case 4:
sum4=sum4+1
  break;
case 5:
sum5=sum5+1
  break;
case 6:
sum6=sum6+1
  break;
case 7:
sum7=sum7+1
  break;
case 8:
sum8=sum8+1
  break;
}

}
```

But

```
error: switch quantity not an integer
 switch (res) {
```

How should I solve this?Use a loop,or there is some other solution?

Comment: use std::unordered_map<int,size_t> , value - count of elements,key - number from std::vector<int>

Comment: What you are missing is the loop. You have to run you switch statement once for each element in the vector.

Comment: Is there full guarantee that the values are in range 1..8. If not, what to do with outliers ?

Comment: @Yves Daoust
Yes,because the file is result of clustering process,there are 8 clusters.

Comment: That is useful information.

Comment: In that case, I know that I would personally pick @YvesDaoust's solution instead of the map based one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this easily using an `std::map<int, int>` or `std::unordered_map<int, int>`:

```
std::map<int, int> counter;
for (auto i: res)
  counter[i]++;
```

To see how many of each value are present:

```
for (auto p: counter)
  std::cout << "Value: " << p.first 
            << ", occurrences: " << p.second << std::endl;
```

Note that this is a very general solution, which works for an arbitrary number of `int` values but has some overhead. If you know that you have a fixed set of acceptable values, you can use an array and a simple, perfect hashing function. If those numbers are consecutive, then your "perfect hashing function" is simply a subtraction of an offset (of `1` in your case), as shown in @yvesdaoust's answer.

```
std::array<int, 8> counter{}; // Only 8 values, in range [1, 8]

inline int perf_hash(int n) { return n - 1; }

// WARNING: This will invoke undefined behaviour for i not in range [1,8]
for (auto i: res)
  counter[perf_hash(i)]++;
```

Comment: In fact, instead of "for (auto p: counter)", I would prefer to use  "for (const auto &p: counter )".

Comment: @CreativeMind If you have some profiling results that show that it makes a positive difference, I'd consider it (`std::pair<int, int>` isn't that big)

Comment: Agreed. But I was just talking about general practise.

Comment: A map is overkill for values in range 1..8. It can become dodgy if out-of-range values are silently accepted.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I agree completely. This is a very general solution but yours is better for this particular case. I will add a note.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way, where `x` is the number you want to count, is

`int quantity = std::count(res.begin(), res.end(), x);`

The way I've written it will work for other container types too, not just `std::vector`.

The C++ standard library is full of these powerful features; I suggest you study it.

Comment: Note that this would require looping over the whole vector for each value.

Comment: ...yes; that's an obvious drawback. I'm essentially suggesting an O(N squared) solution to an O(N) problem. But it's very tractable. I'm open to downvotes!

Comment: For 8 values, it could well be quicker than a map.

Answer (score 2):

The good old, efficient, lightweight, forgotten way:

```
int Sum[8]= { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

int Value;
while (inputFile1 >> Value)
    Sum[Value - 1]++;
```

Comment: That is probably the best way if you're absolutely sure of the range, but you need a `-1` in there (range is [1, 8]).

Comment: Yep, just added. Whether range validation is required (and what to do with invalid values) depends on the context.

Comment: why not use `std::array` instead of a c-style array?

Comment: @YoungJohn: Spares 14 keystrokes, compiles faster by 2 ms, and saves an `int` :)